# virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, virtual-destructor

getting a couple errors that it's a virtual function with non-virtual destructor. how can i fix this error? it was working in g++ 4.6.x but i need it to work on an older version of g++. :(

```
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class container{
public:
    ~queue(){
        queuel.clear();
        queuel.~list();
    }
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do stuff with list<t> test
        return temp;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> test;
};

template <typename T>
class container2 : public container<T>{
public:
    virtual T func_x(){
        T temp;
        //do different stuff with list<T> test
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: woah - can you fix the code sample? You are defining `~queue` inside `container<>` and why are you calling a destructor  explicitely?

Comment: If you want to get a good answer I recommend posting code that compiles. Furthermore you cannot call destructors like you did with ``queuel.~list();``

Comment: @grundprinzip: Yes, you *can* invoke a destructor explicitly, even though there is probably no reason to do so here.

Comment: @grundprinzip: You can invoke a destructor explicitly. In fact You **must** do so if you are using an *placement new*, apart from that there is practically no scenario where you would need to call the destructor yourself.

Comment: http://ideone.com/0H3u4 : This code does not produce the error you mention. How do you expect us to help? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints/ and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: @Als has a point, the destructor is also incorrectly named for your class. Updated answer.

The problem is just that g++ thinks that since you have virtual methods in the class, you should have a virtual destructor. This has to do with that if you inherit a class and extend it, you may allocate memory or other resources that the base class destructor has no idea about cleaning up, and if your destructor is not virtual, the base class' destructor may be called in some cases instead of your real destructor.

The rule of thumb is, if you have virtual methods in your class, use a virtual destructor. Removing the incorrectly named destructor ~queue and putting

```
virtual ~container();
```

in your class declaration and impementing the destructor in the .cpp file should fix your problem.

Comment: Just putting `virtual ~Queue() {}` in the class is usually sufficient.  Base classes generally don't have any data members, and in practice, the base class destructor will only be called from the destructors of the derived class (so the inlining works).

Comment: @LucTouraille For that matter, from a design point of view, the class doesn't look like it should have any virtual functions:-).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Good explanation, except I'm confused about one point. Did you mean "the base class's `destructor` may be called" at the end of your answer?